# docker-compose: Not able to connect to memcached container

Tags: ruby, docker, docker-compose, memcached

I am learning docker. i want to add caching functionality in my application and hence using memcached. below is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:
 app:
   build: .
   volumes: 
    - .:/project 
   command: 'rails s -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3000' 
   container_name: 'test_rails'
   ports:
    - 3000:3000
   depends_on:
     - database
   links:
    - memcached  
 database:
  image: postgres:latest
  volumes:
    - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: docker-user
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: docker-password
    POSTGRES_DB: docker-db
 memcached:
  build:
   context: .
   dockerfile: Dockerfile.memcached
  command: 'tail -f /dev/null'
```

when i am trying to connect to memcached server which is inside `memcached` container from `app` container using below code

```
require 'dalli'
options = { :namespace => "app_v1", :compress => true }
dc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211', options)
```

Then i am getting below error

```
WARN -- : localhost:11211 failed (count: 0) Errno::EADDRNOTAVAIL: Cannot assign requested address - connect(2) for "localhost" port 11211
Dalli::RingError: No server available
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dalli-2.7.10/lib/dalli/ring.rb:46:in `server_for_key'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dalli-2.7.10/lib/dalli/client.rb:367:in `perform'
    from /usr/local/bundle/gems/dalli-2.7.10/lib/dalli/client.rb:130:in `set'
    from (irb):4
    from /usr/local/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

can someone help me in understanding and resolving this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not access one docker service from another service using localhost as each service has its own ip address and like small vm of its own. Use service name instead of localhost and docker will resolve it with ip addres of target service,

```
`dc = Dalli::Client.new('memcached:11211', options)`
```

Comment: i tried it but unfortunately its not working... i also tried with `ip` address but that also is not working...

Comment: What error you are getting after trying mentioned approach

Comment: i made mistake... port 11211 was not exposed and hence was not able to access it...i undestand this after trying mecached image present on dockerhub instead of custome memcached image..  i was able to access memcached when using dockerhub image. the difference between dockerhub image and custome image was that custom image was not exposing port 11211

Comment: i thought exposing port 11211 will resolve my issue but still its not working for me.. i am able to ping to `memcached` service from `app` service using `ping memcached` command but not able to connect using `Dalli::Client.new('memcached:11211', options)` from `app` service. what   is that which i am missing

Comment: i start memcached service using `/usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 0.0.0.0` instead of `/usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1` and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Change :

```
dc = Dalli::Client.new('localhost:11211', options)
```

to :

```
dc = Dalli::Client.new('memcached:11211', options)
```

When you set up containers from compose they are all connected to the default network created by compose. `memcached` is in this case the DNS name of `memcached` container and will be resolved to container IP automatically.

Comment: i tried it but unfortunately its not working... i also tried with `ip` address but that also is not working...

Comment: i made mistake... port 11211 was not exposed and hence was not able to access it...i undestand this after trying mecached image present on dockerhub instead of custome memcached image.. i was able to access memcached when using dockerhub image. the difference between dockerhub image and custome image was that custom image was not exposing port 11211 – Sanjay Salunkhe just now    Edit    Delete

Comment: i thought exposing port 11211 will resolve my issue but still its not working for me.. i am able to ping to `memcached` service from `app` service using `ping memcached` command but not able to connect using `Dalli::Client.new('memcached:11211', options)` from `app` service. what   is that which i am missing

Comment: i start memcached service using `/usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 0.0.0.0` instead of `/usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1` and it works for me